# django template widthratio result as comma separated

Tags: django, django-templates

{% widthratio A 1 B %} gives A*B as numeric, and I need the result as comma separated. Eg. -

```
{% widthratio 100 1 100 %}
```

gives 10000 and I need 10,000. Any idea how it can be done?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/

Comment: I know how filters are used, but I dont have any variable storing the A*B value to which I can apply the filter.

Answer (score 2):

This is what you are looking for

```
{% load humanize %}

{{ my_num|intcomma }}
```

Make sure   you have `django.contrib.humanize` installed in your INSTALLED_APPS

Answer (score 0):

You can use **as** to save it as a varibale as mentioned below,

```
{% widthratio 100 1 100 as total_value %}
{{total_value | intcomma }}
```

*Visit the django documentation for the reference [built-in template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/)*